# Testing methods mocking ApexAsynJob

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, salesforce, apex

I have the following issue. Here is my target apex class that  Ineed to test:

```
class TargetClass {
    public static Id BatchId {get; set;} 
    public void methodOne() {
        //adding an ApexAsyncJob in database and assign its ID ot BatchId
    }

    @Remote
    public static String methodTwo(string batchId) {
        //gets the ApexAsynJob inserted in previous method from database and         //do some operations with it 
    }
}
```

And here is my testing class

```
@isTest
public TargetClassTest() {
    static testmethod void test() {
        test.startTest();
        TargetClass tgtClass = new TargetClass();
        tgtClass.methodOne();
        TargetClass.methodTwo(TargetClass.BatchId);
    }
}
```

When methodOne is done and methdTwo is called, we have the BatchId property assigned but the AsynApexJob is not in the database yet so methodtwo throws an exception. How can I solve it and finish my tests.
I have the following ideas
1. run methodTwo whenever the AsynApexJob is in the database. How can I do this?  An endless loop checking the database doesn't work as we hit the limit of queries.
2. Mocking an AsyncApexJob. I dont necessarily need the AsynApexJob inserted in methodOne. Any would work. I don't know how to do it. When I tried to insert one in the database, I got an error message that INSERT insn't available in AsynApexJob.
It would be fine if someone can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can querying out the jobs, so after you schedule the job you can do this and then assert that the job was actually scheduled ..

```
List<AsyncApexJob> jobInfo = [SELECT Status,NumberOfErrors FROM AsyncApexJob];
System.assertEquals(jobInfo.size(), 1);
```